# VBScript - No se encuentra el método GetRows al migrar de MSDAORA a OraOLEDB.Oracle

Tags: oracle, asp, vbscript

Estamos migrando de un Windows 7 a Windows 10 en una PC para desarrollo, y ya no disponemos en W10 del `MSDAORA.1` para acceder a recursos de *ODBC* y conectar una aplicación a la BBDD de Oracle. Hemos resuelto la conexión y el acceso a consultas generales, pero al intentar obtener todos los datos de un ref_cursor que devuelve un SP en la base, el método `GetRows()` del `RecordSet` simplemente no funciona. No lo reconoce como propiedad o método.

Conexión:

```vb
DSN="PROVIDER=OraOLEDB.Oracle;USER ID=XXXXXX;PASSWORD=XXXXX;DATA SOURCE=XXXXX.WORLD;"
set conn = server.createobject("ADODB.connection")
conn.open DSN
```

Codigo:

```vb
    Set oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
set oRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

oCmd.ActiveConnection = conn
oCmd.CommandType = 4 ' Stored Procedure
oCmd.NamedParameters = True
oCmd.CommandText = "PKG_XXXX.GetXXXX"
' ------------------------------------------------------------------
oCmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = True
' ------------------------------------------------------------------
oRs = oCmd.Execute
' ------------------------------------------------------------------
Set oDataGrid = New caDataGrid 
If oRs.Count > 0 Then
    Session("SIZE_PAGINA") = oRs.Count
    Session("ASPDataGrid") = oRs.GetRows
    oRs.MoveFirst()
    oDataGrid.SetDatos = oRs.GetRows
    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------
    oCmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = False
    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------
    oCmd = Nothing
    oRs = Nothing
    GetListaMotivos = True
    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------
Else
    ReDim aData(0, 0)
    Session("ASPDataGrid") = aData
    Session("SIZE_PAGINA") = 0
    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------
    oCmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = False
    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------
    oCmd = Nothing
    oRs = Nothing
    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------
    GetListaMotivos = False
End If
```

No he encontrado el motivo para que el método no sea reconocido, ya que en realidad pertenece al `ADODB.Recordset`, y no debería ser afectado por el cambio de conector o de versión de Windows...

De hecho, tuve que reemplazar también este segmento, porque TAMPOCO lo reconoce:

```vb
If Not oRs.Eof Or Not oRs.Bof Then
```

Answer (score 0):

finalmente, aunque no terminé de averiguar por qué se produjo el fallo, al menos he logrado resolverlo.
En primer lugar, agregué la variable oRs al Dim:

```
Dim oCmd, oRs
```

Luego eliminé (si, eliminé) esta línea:

```
set oRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Dejando que la definición del objeto sea implícita al ejecutar la query:

```
set oRs = oCmd.Execute
```

También modifiqué el release de recursos porque de lo contrario dispara errores,

```
set oCmd = Nothing
set oRs = Nothing
```

A partir de esos cambios, funcionó como antes. Por lo que se puede entender, **se debe dejar que el tipo de objeto sea definido en forma implícita**, ya que de lo contrario no lo toma correctamente como ADODB.Recorset.

En realidad no tengo idea de la razón del cambio de comportamiento, especialmente porque ese código fuente estaba funcionando correctamente desde al menos 2015 a la fecha, y sigue funcionando en los servidores productivos.Por lo que parece, **el cambio de entorno impacta en el intérprete de VBScript de ASP en el IIS**.
Sólo comenzó a fallar cuando migré desde el ambiente de un Windows 7 64 bits, a Windows 10 de 64 bits. Esto es algo que ya me ha sucedido en ocasión de cambiar el entorno de pruebas desde un Windows Server 2000, a Windows Server 2003.
En cualquier caso, espero que esto le sirva a alguien más.